# Create interceptor qualifier thats ignore annotation value()

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld, qualifiers

Is there a way to create a interceptor qualifier annotation that ignores the annotation string value for qualifying?

for example:

**Log.java**

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Log {
    String value() default ""; // <---- ignore this
}
```

**LogInterceptor.java**

```
@Log
@Interceptor
public class LogInterceptor implements Serializable {

    ...
}
```

**Usage.java**

```
@Log("message for this log")
public String interceptedMethod(String param) {
    ...
}
```

This doesn't work because the annotation `value("message for this log")` works as qualifier but I want to use the `value()` not as qualifier, but message log.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the @Nonbinding annotation for that purpose. You can force the container to ignore a member of a qualifier type by annotating the member @Nonbinding. Look at the following example:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface PayBy {
   PaymentMethod value();
   @Nonbinding String comment() default "";
}
```

Here the comment will be ignored when matching beans by the @PayBy qualifier.
A reference to the CDI documentation describing this can be found [here](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#d0e1309).